# How to put a TextInput at the bottom of the screen in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I make a chat app and I want to put the TextInput at the bottom of the page, but I can't manage to do it . If  I try with position: 'absolute' + bottom: 0 the display is empty. I think I have a problem with a flex in my style , I'm not sure.

Here's my code for MessageScreen:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Wallpaper>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding'>
          <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ message: text })}
           // value={this.state.email}
            placeholderTextColor='white'
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          />
            <Button onPress={this.send} title='SEND' />
              </View>
               </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </Wallpaper>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    paddingLeft: 25
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)',
    width: DEVICE_WIDTH ,
    height: 40,
    color: '#ffffff'
  },
 image: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40
  }
});
```

Here's the Wallpaper:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Image style={styles.picture} source={require('src/components/images/wallpaper.png')}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Image>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  picture: {
    flex: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  }
});
```

Comment: Where will you place the list of messages? I thought maybe you could do it by giving the wrapper for view `TextInput` and view the message list is different, so later you can do the style in both.

Answer (score 12):

try this.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
 <KeyboardAvoidingView 
   style={{position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}}
   behavior="position"
 >
  <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ message: text })}
    // value={this.state.email}
    placeholderTextColor='white'
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
  />
  <Button onPress={this.send} title='SEND' />
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

working example can found [here](https://snack.expo.io/ryjRKap_b)